# Extending parallelogram one side parallel to another and join it to opposite vertex

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have below question:

[image]

Below is my try on the question:
$\angle ZYM=\angle NYO$

$MY=YN$

$\angle ZMY=\angle YNO$

So, $\Delta MZY \cong \Delta NOY$

Therefore, $OY=ZY$

$ZY=OX+XY$

$ZY=27+18=45cm$

But the answer of this question is 22.5cm. I don't know where I did go wrong. Can anyone help me in the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Your work is correct. Just apply midpoint theorem

Comment: @Math Lover in which triangle? Why I am getting double of what should be the correct answer?

Comment: You are not getting double of the correct answer. They are getting half of the correct answer. In $\triangle OPZ, OP \parallel MY$ and $OP = 2 MY$

Comment: But in their solution they have done it by showing triangles ZMY and ZPO to be similar, which deduces that $OY=2ZY$, which is also correct.

Comment: Yes because I didn't pay attention to the given lengths. The question is then incorrect because two given pieces of information are inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is incorrect due to the unnecessary extra condition given $MY=YN$. From just the fact that $MNOP$ is a parallelogram and $Z$ lying on $PM$ and $OY$, using the lengths of $OX=27$, $XY=18$, it can be shown that $\triangle OXP \sim \triangle YXN$ with ratio $OX:XY=3:2$. This means $YN = 2/3 \, OP = 2/3 \, MN$ which contradicts $MY=YN$.

It follows that $\triangle ZMY \sim \triangle ZPO$ with ratio $1:3$. This is equivalent to $YZ=OY/2=45/2=22.5$, giving correct answer.